# Big Theta Questions

Tags: big-o

I don't understand this situation.

f(n) ∈ O(g(n)),
g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n))

for these situations why is are the following the correct answers.

f(n) <= g(n) for all n>1, neither always true or false

g(n) ∈ Ω(f(n)), always true

f(n)<= Θ(g(n)), always true

My logic is since g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n)), g(n) and f(n) would have to have the same highest power (for example: n=n, n^2=n^2). In that case, wouldn't all 3 statements be true?

I don't understand why the first one is neither always true or false and third one is always true.

Comment: See the formal definition of O(n), the question is not about highest powers

Comment: Hi @user3728320. If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you don't think the answer solves your question, consider giving feedback or updating your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Big-O, Big-Ω and Big-Θ notation, in mathematics, describes the asymptotic behaviour of a function, as an upper bound, lower bound and a tight bound (upper and lower bound), respectively. On SE, in the context of programming, we usually use these notations to describe the asymptotic behaviour of algorithms, with regard to the size of the problem that the algorithm is intended to solve (typically this size is denoted n).

For reference, see e.g.
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/asymptotic-notation

For answering your question, we shall treat this subject in the context of the asymptotic (/limiting) behaviour or functions. Lets cover your two properties of and three statements of f(n) and g(n) one by one.

**Property i)** *f(n) ∈ O(g(n))*

Given is that

```
f(n) ∈ O(g(n)).
```

For some constant k>0, (the dominant term(s) of) g(n) provides an upper bound to the asymptotic behaviour of f(n), i.e.,

```
f(n) < k*g(n), n sufficiently large.                   (*)
```

As a quick example of what I mean by dominant terms: if g(n) is a some polynomial, we have

```
O(g(n)) = O(a_0 + a_1*n + ... + a_j*n^j) = O(n^j),
```

i.e., asymptotically dominant term n^j.

**Property ii)** *g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n))*

Given is that

```
g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n)).
```

For some constants k_1>0 and k_2>0, k_1*f(n) and k_2*f(n) provides lower and upper bounds, respectively, on the asymptotic behaviour of g(n), i.e.,

```
k_1*f(n) < g(n) < k_2*f(n), n sufficiently large.      (**)
```

Again, as we describe asymptotic behaviour, it's really the dominant terms of g(n) and f(n) that are of interest.

**Assume from now on that i) and ii) both holds, for all sufficiently large n**

We move only to your three statements.

**Statement a)** *f(n) <= g(n) for all n>1, either always true or false*

First of all, given i) and ii), we cannot draw any conclusion of the behaviour of f(n) and g(n) for "n smaller than sufficiently large n", i.e., we cannot say any statements regarding f(n) and g(n) *for all n>1*. Properties in i) and ii) only describe asymptotic behaviours of f(n) and g(n). If we adjust the statement to

```
f(n) <= g(n) for all sufficiently large n; either always true or false,
```

we can analyse it. Assume the following holds true (for n sufficiently large):

```
f(n) <= g(n).                                          (a1)
```

For n sufficiently large, we also know that (*) and (**) holds, that is

```
(*)  f(n) < k*g(n),       for some constant k>0,       (a2)
(**) f(n) < (1/k_1)*g(n), for some constant k_1>0,     (a3)
     g(n) < k_2*f(n),     for some constant k_2>0,     (a4)
```

Since (a1) holds, by assumption, we can consider (a2) and (a3) as redundant by choosing some k=(1/k_1)>1. This leaves us with

```
f(n) <= g(n) < k_2*f(n),  for some constant k_2>0.     (a1, a4)
```

This is simply property ii) above, g(n) ∈ Θ(f(n)), where we've found that constant k_1 = 1 (or, strictly, k_1 very near 1) satisfy the left hand side of (**).

On the other hand, if we assume that f(n) <= g(n) is always false (sufficiently large n), we arrive at the result

```
g(n) < f(n),                                           (a1.false)
g(n) < k_2*f(n),          for some constant k_2>0.     (a4)
```

Which, naturally, holds (k_2=1).

To round off, statement a) is kind of weird.

**Statement b)** *g(n) ∈ Ω(f(n)), always true*

Much like in i) (for upper bound), given that

```
g(n) ∈ Ω(f(n)),
```

then, for sufficiently large n,

```
k*f(n) < g(n),            for some constant k>0,       (b1)
```

holds. We already know this to be true from ii), as this is given in the left hand side of (**)

```
(**) k_1*f(n) < g(n),     for some constant k_1>0.     (b2)
```

Hence, given ii), it is trivial that g(n) ∈ Ω(f(n)) holds.

**Statement c)** *f(n)<= Θ(g(n)), always true*

Recall Big-Θ from ii); f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)) can be described as

```
k_1*g(n) < f(n) < k_2*g(n), n sufficiently large,      (c1)
```

for some constants k_1>0, k_2>0.

In this context, f(n) <= Θ(g(n)) does not make much sense, as O(g(n)) either describes a property of f(n) or set of functions f(n) that conforms to the property O(g(n)) (in context of asymptotic behaviour. From Wikipedia article of Big O notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> "the notation O(g(n)) is also used to denote the set of all functions
>   f(n) that satisfy the relation f(n)=O(g(n)); f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))"

Perhaps the leq operator "<=" has some special meaning in the context of Big-...-notation, but it's not something I have ever encountered myself.